# How to move mouse in games | not just cursor

Tags: python, face-recognition, opencv

i am coding a sort of ai aimbot in python (to use with friends not to ruin others experience) and i need to know how i can move the crosshair/screen without moving just the cursor? I used face recognition to look for faces in a screenshot, then check the position of the face, then lock the crosshair over the position of the face
this is the code i have

`````
import PIL
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput
import win32api, win32con
import time

from PIL import ImageGrab
from pynput import keyboard

MOUSEEVENT_MOVE = 1

def snap():
    print('A pressed')
    ImageBox = None
    im = ImageGrab.grab(ImageBox)
    im.save('screenshot.png')
    im.close()
    image = cv2.imread("screenshot.png")
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
            gray,
            scaleFactor=1.3,
            minNeighbors=3,
            minSize=(30, 30)
    )

    print("Found {0} Faces!".format(len(faces)))

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        print(x)
        print(y)

        xcent = 860
        ycent = 540

        xdiff = x - xcent
        ydiff = y - ycent
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, xdiff, ydiff)

snap()````
`````

Comment: You can use `pywin32` library to simulate mouse inputs. For exemple `win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, diffX, diffY, 0, 0)`

Comment: forgive me for asking such a dumb question, how would i calculate diffx and diffy??

Comment: It's the difference between the position of the face and the current position of the crossair

Comment: I still cant get it to work, it seems to be flicking to a random place each time, i edited the code above